# One configuration to run them all in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, configuration

The "Configuration Properties" menu in visual studio allows one to configure additional properties of the nodes of a project. For example, one can adjust environment variables, additional dependencies etc.

How can one set up one configuration that is then used by all nodes?

Comment: good question.  I have wondered that myself as I was going through all of the mouse clicks needed to set up properties...  I will be watching this thread to see what the answers are.